# Windows 10 blocks QT5 app from using microphone

Tags: audio, qt5, microphone

I compile and run QT5 example from here

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audioinput-example.html

On other PC it runs just fine, but on my current PC Windows 10 seems don't allow me to use microphone.

I am double check and mic works fine in skype and other apps.

When i run example it show me all my mics:

[image: example program screenshot]

as you can see, it detects all mics in system.

But when it starts or when i change mic from list i have this errors in debug, and mic did not work and program did not show any activity:

```
QAudioInput: failed to open audio device
QAudioInput: failed to open audio device
QObject::connect(QIODevice, Unknown): invalid nullptr parameter
QAudioInput: failed to open audio device
QAudioInput: failed to open audio device
QObject::connect(QIODevice, Unknown): invalid nullptr parameter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cause - Kaspersky KES 11 component - Intrusion detection.

After i disable it microphone begins works just fine. So if you use this antivirus just disable this component when you develop apps on qt5.

Even if you add program to group "trusted", when recompile program you need to regroup it again, because it crc changed each time you compile program.